# JavaScript clock not showing current time on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, mobile, timer, clock

I got this JavaScript Code to display the current time on my website, works perfectly for desktop but it doesn't work on mobile devices

It freezes on the time when the user visits the page

Is it any way to make this possible? Something like refresh the script every sec to show the current time or any other solution?

```js
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = GetTime();

function GetTime(){
    var d = new Date();
    var nhour = d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes();
    if (nmin<=9) { 
        nmin = "0" + nmin 
    }
    return nhour+":"+nmin+"";
}
```

```html
<span id="clock"></span>
```

Your help is really appreciated!

**EDIT:** Thanks to **mdickin** I realized the clock doesn't update even in desktop. So the entire code has something wrong.

Comment: When you say it freezes, do you mean the page becomes unresponsive? Or do you mean the time never updates? Because I don't see any way that the time would be updated even on a desktop

Comment: The time doesn't update, and you're right. It doesn't update even on desktop, my bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you could use a setInterval, which runs a function at regular intervals (in milliseconds).

```
function setTime()
{
    document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = GetTime();
}

setInterval(setTime,1000);
```

You could change the number of milliseconds to suit, depending on how accurate you want to be...but I doubt you would need to worry about being more than a second out either way.

Here's a link with more information about [setInterval and setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 2):

Use `setInterval` to run your `GetTime()` function every second:

```js
document.getElementById("clock").innerHTML = GetTime();

function GetTime(){
        var d = new Date();
        var nhour = d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes();
        if (nmin<=9) { 
            nmin = "0" + nmin 
        }
        return nhour+":"+nmin+"";
    }
    
    setInterval(GetTime, 1000); // run GetTime every 1000ms
```

```html
<span id="clock"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple program that I wrote in codepen to create a live JS timer. Basically all you need to do is call the function inside a `setTimeout` function and provide the frequency in milliseconds.

```js
function startTimer() {
  var today = new Date();
  var hours = today.getHours();
  var mins = today.getMinutes();
  var sec = today.getSeconds();
  mins = checkTime(mins);
  sec = checkTime(sec);
  document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML =
    hours + ":" + mins + ":" + sec;
  var t = setTimeout(startTimer, 100);
}

function checkTime(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i
  };
  return i;
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="startTimer()">
  <div id="timer"></div>
</body>
```

Here is the link to my [codepen](http://codepen.io/AshutoshD/pen/Kzjraw)